# gnuplot: yerrorbars with linecolor variable

Tags: gnuplot

I want to draw `yerrorbars` with different colors. I am able to draw points with different colors using the following code:

```
reset
plot "-" using 1:2:3 with points linecolor variable
# x    y   linecolor
-4.0  -3.8   1
-3.0  -2.9   1
-2.0  -2.1   2 
-1.0  -1.2   1
 1.0   1.1   1
 2.0   2.2   2
 3.0   3.3   3 
 4.0   4.5   3
end
```

But I am not sure how to extend this to `yerrrorbars`. When I try and use the following code, the errorbars are colored only with default color. How do I color the errorbars with a specific color?

```
reset
plot "-" using 1:2:($1-$2) with yerrorbars linecolor variable
# x    y   linecolor
-4.0  -3.8   1
-3.0  -2.9   1
-2.0  -2.1   2 
-1.0  -1.2   1
 1.0   1.1   1
 2.0   2.2   2
 3.0   3.3   3 
 4.0   4.5   3
end
```

I found a way to do this by separating the data and then plotting it. But if there is a way  without separating the data it would be a nicer solution.

```
reset
plot "-" using 1:2:($1-$2) with yerrorbars lc 1, \
     "-" using 1:2:($1-$2) with yerrorbars lc 2, \
     "-" using 1:2:($1-$2) with yerrorbars lc 3

# x     y
-4.0  -3.8
-3.0  -2.9
-1.0  -1.2
 1.0   1.1
end

-2.0  -2.1
 2.0   2.2
end

 3.0   3.3
 4.0   4.5
end
```

Comment: I wanted to ask, what do the integers in your 'linecolor' correspond to? The documentation says the number here refers to the colour of a certain linestyle and i've seen elsewhere it saying it corresponds to a linetype. I've tried both but I cannot get the desired colours on my plot. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`using` specifies which columns will be the input for the command. So since your third column is linecolor, and yerrorbars linecolor expects the fourth column to be the line color, you need to specify `using 1:2:($1-$2):3`. So, this is the corrected version of your example:

```
reset
plot "-" using 1:2:($1-$2):3 with yerrorbars linecolor variable
# x    y   linecolor
-4.0  -3.8   1
-3.0  -2.9   1
-2.0  -2.1   2 
-1.0  -1.2   1
 1.0   1.1   1
 2.0   2.2   2
 3.0   3.3   3 
 4.0   4.5   3
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that the third column (`$1 - $2`) is used to plot the yerrorbar (the ydelta more specifically). The documentation:

```
3 columns:  x  y  ydelta
```

You'll **need to add another column** for the linecolor. If you want to make up something fancy, you could do something like:

```
plot "/tmp/test.foo" using 1:2:($1-$2):(int($1)+1) with yerrorbars linecolor variable
```

(e.g. use the integer part of the first column and add 1).

Or you can also use ternary operators if you want to choose between two colors:

```
plot "-" using 1:2:($1  > 1 ? 1 : 3) with yerrorbars linecolor variable
```

(e.g. choose linecolor 1 if the value in the first column is greater than 1, linecolor 3 otherwise)